# Is anyone working on nVidia GPU mining software? How to improve it ourselves? Last release is from 2014.

Tags: gpu-mining, mining-software

I'm currently using [ccminer-cryptonight](https://github.com/tsiv/ccminer-cryptonight/), with the latest release from 2014. I'm mining with a GTX 1080, and I'm just barely getting a higher hashrate than people with a way slower nVidia GPU.

Also, there have been 3 major cuda releases since 2014. Surely there are improvements in the new CUDA releases that wouldn't be that hard to take advantage of?

If nobody is developing anything at the moment, how hard would it be to do? I don't have any experience in developing mining software, but would be willing to give it a shot of anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

There is this [proposal](https://forum.getmonero.org/21/the-thread-cemetery/2355/improved-nvidia-mining-software) but it did not get funded.

Comment: Too bad :( I see two commenters saying they donated 1000 each. How about reviving the  proposal?

Comment: You can always try :)